# Integrating script with git autocomplete

Tags: macos, bash, script, git, autocomplete

I have an extremely simple bash script I use quite a bit when I'm working with Git and Pods:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch=$1
git checkout $branch && pod install
```

However, my branch names are sometimes a little cumbersome to type, so I've added the git-completion.bash script to my .bash-profile. That worked great on its own, but unfortunately it doesn't play well with my little script.

How can I get my script to use git-completion on its parameter? Alternately, how else might I get the functionality of my script as well as branch autocompletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that. First you can turn that script into a function and put it in your `.bashrc` file.

Create a function called (whatever you want)`gco` in .bashrc, and tie it into the git bash completer:

```
gco () { git checkout $1 && pod install ; }
__git_complete gco _git_branch
```

You can also use your script as is if it is located on your path (e.g. add ~/bin to your path and move it there). In that case, assuming you called the script `gc`, add the following to your `.bashrc` file ; same syntax as for the function.

```
__git_complete gc _git_branch
```

You can do this with aliases in the same way.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869227/git-autocomplete-in-bash-aliases) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62095/how-to-alias-git-to-g-so-that-bash-completion-rules-are-preserved) for some more info. Some details on how to do this are in the [git-completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) script itself, but its pretty light on specifics (or examples).